# How can I prevent the current memory leaks in my C program?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

I have a program where I load data from a text file into an array of structs.
My struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct A {
    int id;
    char* name;
    char* desc;
} A;
```

I start loading the file from my main function:

```
int main(void) {
    A* a;
    int* length = 0;
    arr = betolt("name.txt", &length);
    ...
    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Then - in a different header file - the real logic happens like this:

```
A* load(char* file_name, int* length) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) return NULL;
    size_t ar_length = 500;
    size_t line_counter = 0;
    char** lines = malloc(ar_length);
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        lines[line_counter] = malloc(256);
        strcpy(lines[line_counter], line);
        line_counter++;
        if(line_counter > sizeof(lines)){
            ar_length *= 2;
            lines = realloc(lines, ar_length);
        }
    }
    *length = line_counter;
    fclose(fp);
    return process(lines, line_counter);
}

A* process(char** lines, int length) {
    A* arr = (A*) malloc(length * sizeof(A));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        char* line = lines[i];
        char* ptr = strtok(line, ";");
        A a;
        a.id = i;
        int j = 0;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            if (j == 0) {
                a.name = ptr;
            } else if (j == 1) {
                a.desc = ptr;
            }
            j++;
            ptr = strtok(NULL, ";");
        }
        arr[i] = a;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

My program works just fine, however, I got memory leaks for each loaded line because of the `malloc(256)`, and I also got memory leak after using `realloc(lines, ar_length);`
I'm quite unsure why I get these leaks because isn't it supposed to "automatically free" the memory after a function runs?
How can I fix these memory leaks?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `strdup` rather than allocating a buffer of arbitrary length, hoping it will work. And simply free all of the allocations at the end. Also, `sizeof(lines)` does not do what you think it does and will quickly blow up your memory if `line_counter` gets bigger than your pointer size (probably 8).

Comment: Also, the last token of every line is going to contain a newline character. I'm not sure whether that is what you want/need/expect.

Comment: This is just plain wrong: `A* arr = (A*) malloc(length * sizeof(length));`

Comment: I miswrote that that is sizeof(A)

Comment: I tried to call free on arr at the end of process function, but then my array will not hold the data anymore correctly

Comment: @Cheatah can you please give me solutions to the problems you stated?

Answer (score 0):

There are several general problems with your code.

1. Casting result of malloc is considered a bad practice. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/4885321) for details.
2. Realloc can fail and return NULL without freeing the original pointer, you are not taking it into consideration. A better way would be +- this:

```c
int* x = malloc(200*sizeof(int));
//whatever
int* bigger_x = realloc(x, 400*sizeof(int));
if(bigger_x) x = bigger_x;
else handle_error("realloc");
```

As for points more specific to your question and problems:

3. > I'm quite unsure why I get these leaks because isn't it supposed to "automatically free" the memory after a function runs? How can I fix these memory leaks?

No, it's not. Generally you should clean up the used memory once you're done with using it. When? Good question ;) Note, that you're using pointers to the dynamically allocated array, e.g. here: `a.desc = ptr;`.
A trivial solution would be to **str**ing**dup**licate each of those string, i.e.
`a.desc = strdup(ptr);`, then free `lines` after `process()` returns. Note, that you `strdup` actually does allocate, so you need to release the resources allocated by it once you're done with them.

4. Use valgrind or address sanitizer. Simply compile with debug symbols and `-fsanitize=address`, that will give you plenty of info of what and where is leaking. Conteporary version of clang and gcc support it. Valgrind is also a way to go, but it's way less convenient imho.

Bonus point: C does not have RAII, but you can utilize some basic "scope guard" techniques anyway.
Consider the following code:

```c
char* buffer = malloc(300);
if(buffer) {
//do whatever
}
free(buffer);
```

Should you forget about `free()` at the end, you'll have a memleak.
What you can do instead is use for loop in slightly creative way to introduce a "scope guard":

```c
for(char* buffer = malloc(300); buffer; free(buffer), buffer=NULL)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Similar technique should also works for `FILE*` and other resources or can be generalized using macros, it's for you to decide whether you like it or not.